# remix test inside a ubuntu environment

Tags: testing

Im trying to make some test using the [remix test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remix-tests/v/0.1.11) library. I create a VM with a Ubuntu Server 18.04 I update the system to latest version and I install npm and node.

I generate a folder with the following files according to the web page example

[image]

Inside test.js I have write this piece of code:

```
const RemixTests = require('remix-tests');

remixTests.runTest(simple_storage_test.sol, contractObj, testCallback, resultsCallback);
```

I have many doubts

1. params like contractObj, testCallback, resultsCallback i think that I have to change. What is the expected value according to my files?

   2.Once this is executed I have some result file or just appear in the terminal screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remixTests.runTest` will run the tests mentioned in the test file and pass some arguments to the callback as explained [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix/tree/master/remix-tests). You can then use the callback to `console.log` or do something else based on the inputs to the callback function:

`passingNum` - number of passing tests

`failureNum` - number of failing tests

`timePassed` - time it took for all the tests to run (in seconds)

hope this helps.

Comment: The value of contractObj, testCallback, resultsCallback where can I find?

Comment: It is mentioned in the Readme that cotractObject is the web3.js 1.0 contract instance. You can read more about contract instance here:https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html. The testCallback and resultsCallback are functions you have to define. testCallback is a function that will be called everytime there is a test event. resultsCallback is a function that is called at the end of all the tests as described above.

Comment: You know about some explained example. I mean, instead of the expected parameter explanation. Something with a real implementation.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find any example of using. I will try and come up with an example asap. I am a bit busy now.